# how to validate only show me geometric shapes smaller than a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, shapes, graphics2d

I can make a program to enter a series of values ​​of geometric figures to show me in a JFrame.
It happens all the figures showing they want to see in the JFrame, but I have to validate that these figures appear to me entirely in the JFrame is not the case when the coordinates are very large.
I was looking online and found nothing.
I thought that "if" but never finished, because each number and the radio that I have to enter a validation.
I wondered if there was a reserved word in java that allows me to display only the data that is smaller than the JFrame.

Thank you for your response.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your favourite answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

There are many methods you can use in the [Shape](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html) class. E.g. `getBounds()` and `contains(double x, double y)`

Comment: +1 See also [`createTransformedShape()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#createTransformedShape%28java.awt.Shape%29).